# Different resource collection output for one model based on API version in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to have two different API version and want to have two different output of UserCollection. I've tried this:

```
class Branch extends JsonResource
{
    private $usage;

    public function __construct($resource, $usage = null) {
        $this->usage = $usage;
        parent::__construct($resource);
    }

    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'    => (string) $this->id,
            'code'  => $this->code,
            'name'  => $this->name,
            $this->mergeWhen($this->usage == 'select-branch', [
                'address'   => $this->address,
                'phone'     => $this->phone,
            ]),
             $this->mergeWhen($this->usage == 'api', [
                'bank_id'   => $this->bank_id,
            ]),
        ];
    }
}
```

and no change in UserCollection.

But the first element has both merges and there is no merge for the rest.

`dd($this->usage)` in the Resource when I call it from a collection is 0 for the first Resource, 1 for the second and so on.

Comment: It seems okay to me. I tried in my project as well. Seems like all fine. Can you just `dd($this->usage)`? And, where did you get that `$result` variable?

Comment: @ssi-anik Sorry `$result` was a mistake, `dd($this->result)` when I call it from a collection is `0` for the first Resource, `1` for the second and so on.

Comment: you try dd in your constructor.

Comment: @ssi-anik Same result in Resource constructor

Comment: I told you to check the `$usage` variable in the constructor. cause, 0 == 'select-branch' is true. so is 0 == 'api'. Check what you're getting in your constructor as `$usage`.

Comment: @ssi-anik Excuse me, it's also 0, 1, 2, 3

Comment: if it's numeric and string at the same time, you should rather check `===` instead of `==`. when you're passing 0 and checking a string with `==`, it's causing the error.

Comment: I'm not passing the `0, 1, 2, 3` arguments to ResourceCollection, I passed `api` argument.

Comment: your replies seems vague to me. use `===` and check the result.